# Printer installation

Tags: lan, network-printer, laser-printer, hp-laserjet, rj-45

Scenario :

> Four PCs on LAN connected to each other.
>
> Printer (HP Laserjet 2100/M/TN with Parallel(LPT) Port and Rj45 female connector) directly connected to one of the PCs through Parallel (LPT) Port.
>
> Now,I want to install my printer on LAN as an individual device (through RJ45),so that any one can put print commands on this printer ( without any connectivity to PC through LPT ).

I need solution for this,because by doing this my printer will run PC free(individually) on LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following the [instructions from HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=25469&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=25469&objectID=bpl06697)?

Where does it go wrong?